# Displaying progress bar for long running process in Actionscript/Flash Builder without mixing logic

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, progress-bar, flex3

I'm working on an application that processes (possibly large reaching one or two million lines) text (in tab separated form) files containing detail of items and since the processing time can be long I want to update a progress bar so the user knows that the application didn't just hang, or better, to provide an idea of the remaining time.

I've already researched and I know how to update a simple progress bar but the examples tend to be simplistic as to call something like progressBar.setProgress(counter++, 100) using Timer, there are other examples where the logic is simple and written in the same class. I'm also new to the language having done mostly Java and some JavaScript in the past, among others.

I wrote the logic for processing the file (validation of input and creation of output files). But then, if I call the processing logic in the main class the update will be done at the end of processing (flying by so fast from 0 to 100) no matter if I update variables and try to dispatch events or things like that; the bar won't reflect the processing progress.

Would processing the input by chunks be a valid approach? And then, I'm not sure if the processing delay of one data chunk won't affect the processing of the next chunk and so on, because the timer tick is set to be 1 millisecond and the chunk processing time would be longer than that. Also, if the order of the input won't be affected or the result will get corrupted in some way. I've read multithreading is not supported in the language, so should that be a concern?

I already coded the logic described before and it seems to work:

```
// called by mouse click event
function processInput():void { 
    timer = new Timer(1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, processChunk);
    timer.start();
}

function processChunk(event:TimerEvent):void {

    // code to calculate start and end index for the data chunk, 
    // everytime processChunk is executed these indexes are updated

    var dataChunk:Array = wholeInputArray.splice(index0, index1);

    processorObj.processChunk(dataChunk)

    progressBar.setProgress(index0, wholeInputArray.length); 
    progressBar.label = index0 + " processed items";

    if(no more data to process) { // if wholeInputArray.length == index1
        timer.stop();

        progressBar.setProgress(wholeInputArray.length, wholeInputArray.length); 
        progressBar.label = "Processing done";

        // do post processing here: show results, etc.
    }   
}
```

The declaration for the progress bar is as follows:

```
<mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" x="23" y="357" width="411" direction="right" 
labelPlacement="center" mode="manual" indeterminate="false" />
```

I tested it with an input of 50000 lines and it seems to work generating the same result as the other approach that processes the input at once. But, would that be a valid approach or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your solution is good, i use it most of time. 
But multithreading is now supported on AS3 (for desktop and web only for the moment). 
Have a look at: [Worker documentation](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) and [Worker exemple](http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world). 
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'd like to discard the possibility that the execution of processing units (the processing of a chunk) won't overlap each other (I think they won't because at the time this is not programmed for concurrency). Should I worry about that? I also will be trying Workers. Thanks.

Comment: As AndySavage said, the processes won't overlap, the timer events won't be dispatched while your program is running on the chunk if your processing code is blocking.

Comment: Instead of using timer and timer events you can use the EnterFrame event too

Answer (score 0):

may I ask if this Timer AS IS is the working Timer ??? because IF YES then you are in for a lot of trouble with your Application in the long run! - re loading & getting the Timer to stop, close etc. The EventListener would be incomplete and would give problems for sure!

I would like to recommend to get this right first before going further as I know from experience as in some of my own AIR Applications I need to have several hundred of them running one after another in modules as well as in some of my web Apps. not quiet so intense yet a few!
I'm sure a more smother execution will be the reward! regards aktell

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That code is the simplified version but reflects the current approach. I start and end the timer only once (there's no stop/resume intended). What I expect of the code is for each timer tick to trigger the processing of the next chunk of data (being them fixed length -- let's say 100 text lines each), I suppose the chunks will be processed one after another and never in parallel.

I think processing chunks in multithreads is not necessary but processing by chunks currently allows me to give the GUI a break so it can get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html). Because splitting data into chunks and then processing it is a valid but quite cumbersome approach and with workers you can simply spawn a background worker, do all the parsing there and return a result, all without blocking GUI. Worker approach should require less time to do parsing, because there is no need to stop parser and wait for the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

Workers would be an ideal solution, but quite complicated to set up. If you're not up to it right now, here's a PseudoThread solution I use in similar situations which you can probably get up and running in 5 minutes:

[Pseudo Threads](http://adobefreaks.blogspot.com/2012/02/flash-thread-pseudo-thread-solution.html)

It uses EnterFrame events for balancing between work and letting the UI does its thing and you can manually update the progress bar within your 'thread' code. I think it would be easily adapted for your needs since your data is easily sliced.

Answer (score 0):

Without using  Workers (which it seems you are not yet familiar with) AS3 will behave single threaded. Your timers will not overlap. If one of your chunks takes more than 1s to complete the next timer event will be processed when it can. It will not queue up further events if it takes more than your time period ( assuming your processing code is blocking).

The previous answers show the "correct" solution to this, but this might get you where you need to be faster.